# Jedis ERR only (P)SUBSCRIBE / (P)UNSUBSCRIBE / PING / QUIT allowed in this context

Tags: java, minecraft, jedis

all of a sudden when I try to send a message, I get this error. I don't know why. This has worked fine for a while but then it just stopped working when I tried to send a message. Sometimes it actually sends the message even though the error is thrown but in the listeners, the message is null. I have no idea why this is happening.

```
redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisDataException: ERR only (P)SUBSCRIBE / (P)UNSUBSCRIBE / PING / QUIT allowed in this context
    at redis.clients.jedis.Protocol.processError(Protocol.java:127) ~[?:?]
    at redis.clients.jedis.Protocol.process(Protocol.java:161) ~[?:?]
    at redis.clients.jedis.Protocol.read(Protocol.java:215) ~[?:?]
    at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.readProtocolWithCheckingBroken(Connection.java:340) ~[?:?]
    at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.getIntegerReply(Connection.java:265) ~[?:?]
    at redis.clients.jedis.Jedis.publish(Jedis.java:2690) ~[?:?]
    at com.cursehq.core.communicator.CoreCommunicator.sendMessage(CoreCommunicator.java:117) ~[?:?]
```

Here is the communicator class
    package com.cursehq.core.communicator;

```
import com.cursehq.core.Core;
import com.cursehq.core.api.communicator.Communicator;
import com.cursehq.core.api.communicator.listener.CommunicatorListener;
import com.cursehq.core.communicator.listeners.*;
import com.cursehq.core.communicator.message.Message;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;
import org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPoolConfig;
import redis.clients.jedis.*;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class CoreCommunicator implements Communicator {
    private final Set<CommunicatorListener> listeners = new HashSet<>();
    private final Gson gson = new Gson();
    private JedisPool pool;
    private String server;

    public boolean load() {
        String host = Core.getCore().getConfig().getString("redis.host");
        int port = Core.getCore().getConfig().getInt("redis.port");
        String password = Core.getCore().getConfig().getString("redis.password");
        server = Core.getCore().getConfig().getString("redis.server");

        try {
            pool = new JedisPool(new GenericObjectPoolConfig(), host, port, 20000, password);
            loadServer();
            loadListener();
            loadListeners();
            Core.log("&7Successfully connected to the redis communicator!");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    public void unload() {
        try (Jedis jedis = pool.getResource()) {
            String json = jedis.get("servers");
            Set<String> set = gson.fromJson(json, new TypeToken<Set<String>>(){}.getType());
            set.remove(server.toLowerCase());
            jedis.set("servers", gson.toJson(set));
            jedis.persist("servers");
        }
    }

    private void loadServer() {
        try (Jedis jedis = pool.getResource()) {
            Set<String> set;
            String json = jedis.get("servers");
            if (json == null)
                set = new HashSet<>();
            else
                set = gson.fromJson(json, new TypeToken<Set<String>>(){}.getType());

            set.add(server.toLowerCase());
            jedis.set("servers", gson.toJson(set));
            jedis.persist("servers");
        }
    }
    private void loadListener() {
        new Thread(() -> {
            try (Jedis jedis = pool.getResource()) {
                jedis.subscribe(new JedisPubSub() {
                    public void onMessage(String channel, String msg1) {
                        Message message = gson.fromJson(msg1, Message.class);
                        String type = message.getType();
                        String msg = message.getMessage();
                        String from = Core.getCore().getUtils().capitalize(message.getFrom());

                        listeners.stream()
                                .filter(listener -> listener.getType().equalsIgnoreCase(type))
                                .forEach(listener -> listener.onMessageReceive(msg, from));
                    }
                }, "all", server.toLowerCase());
            }
        }).start();
    }
    private void loadListeners() {
        new AnnouncementListener();
        new CommandListener();
        new RankUpdateListener();
        new ServerStatusListener();
        new StaffChatListener();
    }

    public JedisPool getPool() {
        return pool;
    }
    public String getServerName() {
        return server;
    }
    public String getServers() {
        try (Jedis jedis = pool.getResource()) {
            String json = jedis.get("servers");
            Set<String> servers = gson.fromJson(json, new TypeToken<Set<String>>(){}.getType());
            return String.join(", ", servers);
        }
    }
    public boolean serverExists(String string) {
        try (Jedis jedis = pool.getResource()) {
            Set<String> servers = gson.fromJson(jedis.get("servers"), new TypeToken<Set<String>>(){}.getType());
            return servers.contains(string.toLowerCase());
        }
    }

    public void sendMessage(String type, String msg) {
        sendMessage(type, msg, "all");
    }
    public void sendMessage(String type, String msg, String to) {
        try (Jedis jedis = pool.getResource()) {
            Message message = new Message(type, msg);
            String json = gson.toJson(message);
            jedis.publish(to.toLowerCase(), json);
        }
    }

    public Set<CommunicatorListener> getListeners() {
        return listeners;
    }
}
```

If anyone knows what could be causing this error, please share.

Answer (score 0):

We met the same problem not long ago. The reason is that the same `Jedis` instance execute other commands after execute `subscribe` command. It may be a little confused, because JedisPool was used, and `subscribe` will not return jedis instance to `Pool` since it is blocked.
But from the log I found that `subscribe` will relase after an exception happend on method `onMessage`.
So even `Pool` was used, `subscribe` and other commands can still use a same Jedis instance in some unexpected case.
And we finally use different jedis pool to separate `subscribe` from other command.

Maybe use `Jedis#disconnect` for subscribe is more proper.

```
        Jedis jedis = null;
        try {
            jedis = jedisPool.getResource();
            jedis.subscribe(new JedisPubSub() {
                @Override
                public void onMessage(String channel, String message) {
                    System.out.println(message);
                }
            }, "topic1");
        } finally {
            if (jedis != null) {
                jedis.disconnect();
                jedis.close();
            }
        }
```

Comment: we can also set `redis.pool.testOnReturn=true` to avoid the problem, but there is a little performance lose.